# Constraint layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

If I use only layout_constraint_guide_percentage guidelines in layout make widget (button, editbox) to match constraint in all 4 directions to guidelines.

Is this right approach for making design more responsive?

[image]

What are pros. or cons. if I use this method. Is this right way to use constraint layout? If not what is proper approach for making design more responsive that support all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like you have mentioned, but using guidelines for this scenario is not suitable solution. So you can do it easily with the help of another constraint layout feature that is chaining between your button and editbox